# berkeley DB on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, berkeley-db

I'm trying to use Berkely DB on GAE and everything worked fine except the logging. Here is the code snippet

```
EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig();
        envConfig.setAllowCreate(allowCreateNew);
        envConfig.setConfigParam(EnvironmentConfig.FILE_LOGGING_LEVEL, "OFF");
        envConfig.setConfigParam(EnvironmentConfig.CONSOLE_LOGGING_LEVEL, "OFF");
        envConfig.setLoggingHandler(null);
        envConfig.setReadOnly(isReadOnly);
        envConfig.setTransactional(false);
        if (cacheSize != null)
            envConfig.setCacheSize(cacheSize);
        env = new Environment(dbPath, envConfig);
```

As can be seen I have disabled logging and my logging.properties file on GAE is

```
.level = WARNING
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=OFF
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Set the default logging level for ORM, specifically, to WARNING
DataNucleus.JDO.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Utility.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level=WARNING
java.sql.level=WARNING
```

i followed all the pointers given by others from stackoverflow but still I'm getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at 

    com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
        at com.sleepycat.je.utilint.ConsoleRedirectHandler.<init>(ConsoleRedirectHandler.java:26)
        at com.sleepycat.je.utilint.LoggerUtils.getLogger(LoggerUtils.java:198)
        at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.StartupTracker.<init>(StartupTracker.java:151)
        at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.<init>(EnvironmentImpl.java:437)
        at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.<init>(EnvironmentImpl.java:410)
        at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbEnvPool.getEnvironment(DbEnvPool.java:178)
        at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.makeEnvironmentImpl(Environment.java:251)
        at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:232)
        at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:176)
```

Any pointers on how to disabled logging from Berkley DB would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [com.sleepycat.je.utilint.LoggerUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sleepycat/je/5.0.73/com/sleepycat/je/utilint/LoggerUtils.java).getLogger method is always trying to install handlers on the root logger if they are not present.  Specifically it is trying to install:

1. java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
2. com.sleepycat.je.utilint.ConsoleRedirectHandler
3. com.sleepycat.je.utilint.FileRedirectHandler
4. com.sleepycat.je.utilint.ConfiguredRedirectHandler

Changing the logging configuration won't prevent the code from trying to do this.

It does appear that the com.sleepycat.je.utilint.LoggerUtils should be patched to deal with SecurityException thrown by [addHandlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler-java.util.logging.Handler-) and NoClassDefFoundError for classes that extend restricted classes.

Comment: Yes, I did get the source for sleepy cat and removed all the loggers out of it however after jumping that hoop I ran into db file size issues... so abandoning the use of sleepycat.